# Implement Google Custom Search Other Than Via UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to do Google custom searches natively within an iOS app (without using web views)?

Right now the only Google search code I see in the docs is in Javascript.

I also found a Google API here for Objective C but I do not understand how this relates to Custom Search.  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

**So, can Google custom search be implemented with or without a UIWebView?**

Without breaking Google's ToS of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call google custom search web services for your app.

check out this link for more information

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/